# I want to simplify this sequence to be a single nested sum

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation

I want to figure out the exact series on $k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. Is it possible to make a single definition for every $k$, so we just have to substitute the value of $k$ to get the series of each $k$.

$k=0$ ;

$$\;\;ABC$$

$k=1$ ;

$$\;\;A^{4}BC+A^{3}B^{2}C+A^{3}B^{}C^{2}+A^{2}B^{3}C^{}+A^{2}B^{2}C^{2}$$

$k=2$ ;

\begin{eqnarray} \;\;A^{7}BC+A^{6}B^{2}C+A^{6}B^{}C^{2}+A^{5}B^{3}C^{}+A^{5}B^{2}C^{2}+A^{5}B^{}C^{3}+A^{4}B^{4}C^{}+A^{4}B^{3}C^{2}+A^{4}B^{2}C^{3}+A^{3}B^{5}C^{}+A^{3}B^{4}C^{2}+A^{3}B^{3}C^{3}
\end{eqnarray}
$k=3$ ;

\begin{eqnarray}
\;\;A^{10}BC+A^{9}B^{2}C+A^{9}B^{}C^{2}+A^{8}B^{3}C^{}+A^{8}B^{2}C^{2}+A^{8}B^{}C^{3}+A^{7}B^{4}C^{}+A^{7}B^{3}C^{2}+A^{7}B^{2}C^{3}+A^{7}B^{}C^{4}+A^{6}B^{5}C^{}+A^{6}B^{4}C^{2}+A^{6}B^{3}C^{3}+A^{6}B^{2}C^{4}+A^{5}B^{6}C^{}+A^{5}B^{5}C^{2}+A^{5}B^{4}C^{3}+A^{5}B^{3}C^{4}+A^{4}B^{7}C^{}+A^{4}B^{6}C^{2}+A^{4}B^{5}C^{3}+A^{4}B^{4}C^{4}
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have tried to solve thia this
and this is what I have got

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{j} A^{3k+2-j} B^{1-i+j} C^i
+ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} A^{2k+2-j} B^{k+1-i+j} C^i$$

But I want it as a single nested sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out the two sums.

If there are errors in your exponents,
you can do similar things.

$\begin{array}\\
s(k)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{j} a^{3k+2-j} b^{1-i+j} c^i
+ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} a^{2k+2-j} b^{k+1-i+j} c^i\\
&=u(k)+v(k)\\
u(k)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{j} a^{3k+2-j} b^{1-i+j} c^i\\
&=abc\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{j} a^{3k+1-j} b^{-i+j} c^{i-1}\\
&=abc\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} a^{3k+1-j} b^{-i+j+1} c^{i}\\
&=abc\sum_{j=1}^{k} a^{3k+1-j}b^{j+1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}  b^{-i} c^{i}\\
&=abca^{3k+1}b\sum_{j=1}^{k} a^{-j}b^{j}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} (c/b)^{i}\\
&=a^{3k+2}b^2c\sum_{j=1}^{k} (b/a)^j\dfrac{1-(c/b)^j}{1-c/b}\\
&=\dfrac{a^{3k+2}b^2c}{1-c/b}\sum_{j=1}^{k} (b/a)^j(1-(c/b)^j)\\
&=\dfrac{a^{3k+2}b^2c}{1-c/b}\sum_{j=1}^{k} ((b/a)^j-(c/a)^j)\\
&=\dfrac{a^{3k+2}b^2c}{1-c/b}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}(b/a)^j-\sum_{j=1}^{k}(c/a)^j\right)\\
&=\dfrac{a^{3k+2}b^2c}{1-c/b}\left(\dfrac{b/a-(b/a)^{k+1}}{1-b/a}-\dfrac{c/a-(c/a)^{k+1}}{1-c/a}\right)\\
v(k)
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} a^{2k+2-j} b^{k+1-i+j} c^i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} c^i\sum_{j=0}^{k} a^{2k+2-j-1} b^{k+1-i+j+1} \\
&= a^{2k+1}b^{k+2}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} c^ib^{-i}\sum_{j=0}^{k} a^{-j} b^{j} \\
&= a^{2k+1}b^{k+2}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (c/b)^i\sum_{j=0}^{k} (b/a)^j \\
&= a^{2k+1}b^{k+2}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (c/b)^i\dfrac{1-(b/a)^{k+1}}{1-b/a}\\
&= \dfrac{a^{2k+1}b^{k+2}(1-(b/a)^{k+1})}{1-b/a}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (c/b)^i\\
&= \dfrac{a^{2k+1}b^{k+2}(1-(b/a)^{k+1})(c/b-(c/b)^{k+2})}{(1-b/a)(1-c/b)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to expand it.

Comment: Fine. Then stop where I have it just as a single sum.